# Enyo location on Pre3 device

Tags: webos, enyo

I'm just starting to have a look at the enyo framework as I bought a Pre3. I've downloaded the SDK and VM, and also the eclipse plugins to write code in eclipse.

Everything works well, except that the plugins has not been updated to use the enyo framework.

The index.xml file points to mojo :

```
<script src="/usr/palm/frameworks/mojo/mojo.js" type="text/javascript" x-mojo-version="1"></script>
```

So I assume the rest of the skeleton is also using mojo objects ...

It doesn't seem right, the eclipse plugin has not been updated ?

Could I know the enyo.js location on the palm device ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use Eclipse, so this never affected me personally, but my understanding is that HP/Palm never updated the Eclipse plugin for the Enyo framework. I developed my Enyo apps in Notepad++ on Windows and TextWrangler on Mac, testing locally on Chrome or Safari.

Note that you do not need to know the exact location of the Enyo framework on the device. In index.html you need to put the location of Enyo in your computer, as this allows you to test your app on your browser without a device or emulator.

The `palm-package` utility rewrites the `<script>` tag in your index.html to point to the correct place on your phone or emulator when it creates the ipk package.

For a slighly outdated webOS SDK the install locations for Enyo are these:

on Mac OS X:

```
<script src="/opt/PalmSDK/0.1/share/refcode/framework/enyo/0.10/framework/enyo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

on Windows 7 64-bit:

```
<script src="C:/Program Files (x86)/HP webOS/SDK/share/refcode/webos-framework/enyo/0.10/framework/enyo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```